# how to consume json web service in worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

**xml file (HofDetails.xml) for adapter is:**

```
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <domain>172.16.32.44</domain>
  <port>8080</port>
```

**my adapter code is :**
 ***file : HofDetails-impl.js***

```
function getHofDetails(){

    path = "/jsonWebService/rest/UserInfoService/module";

    var input = {
        method : 'get',
        returnedContentType:'plain/json',
        path : path,
        parameters : {
            'Eid' : '0',
            'bhamashahid' : '0',
            'aadhar_id' : '0',
            'mobileNo' : '1'
        }
    };

    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
    //return {result : "12345"};
}
```

**and defination of my web service looks like this :**

```
@GET
@Path("/module/{Eid}/{bhamashahid}/{aadhar_id}/{mobileNo}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getAll(@PathParam("Eid") String eid,@PathParam("bhamashahid") String bhamashahid,@PathParam("aadhar_id") String aadhar,@PathParam("mobileNo") String mobileNo) {

  // return JsonObject.toJsonString();

}
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem you are experiencing? you can't get the JSON response back or what?

Answer (score 0):

You have not actually explained what is the issue you are having.
What is the issue?

Also, it appears that you are not actually processing the response.
How about something like this:

```
var response = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
response.someProperty = "something";

return response;
```